# Cannot read content of response

Tags: angular

In my angular app I use the `httpClient` module for my REST calls. In my component I have:

```
deleteMovie(id: number): void {
  this._dataService.deleteMovie<DeleteMovie>(id)
  .subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data.message);
    this.movies = this.movies.filter(movie => movie.id !== id);
  },
  error => () => {
      'something went wrong';
  },
  () => {
    // console.log(this.movies);
  });
}
```

This is the delete method in the service:

```
public deleteMovie<T>(id: number): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>('/api/movies/' + id, {headers: this.getToken()});
}
```

In the backend controller I have:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteMovie(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){
    System.out.println(movieService.deleteMovie(id));
    return movieService.deleteMovie(id);
}
```

And in the backend service I have:

```
@Override
public String deleteMovie(Integer id) {
    Movie movie = movieRepository.findById(id);
    User current_user = userService.getUser();      
    current_user.removeMovie(movie);
    userRepository.save(current_user);

    return "string";
}
```

My DeleteMovie model:

```
import { Movie } from './movie.model';

export class DeleteMovie {
  message: string;
}
```

Is just a model that (for now) returns a string. Will return more later.

When I run the code, the log shows "string". So in the back-end the string is returned from the service to the controller.

But the console in the browser shows:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of null at SafeSubscriber._next

So why is data null?

Comment: Your delete method return a "string", not a "DeleteMovie" (by the way What is a "DeleteMovie"?). Choose if you want to return a Movie (not a DeleteMovie or a String. If it's a string, in your service use this.http.delete(this.url, { responseType: 'text' })

Comment: initialize a class variable with `any` `public CLSVAR: any =false` type and assign it data like `this.CLSVAR = data` and then access `this.CLSVAR.message`

Comment: @Eliseo I've added the DeleteMovie model. It's just a model that for now has a string property.

Comment: @Peter, perhaps I am wrong, but I understand that you return a string, not a Json Object.

Comment: @Eliseo yes, by adding the responseType text the code works. Makes sense.